# python plotly area chart with Y-axis in percent

Tags: python, plotly

i try to plot the y-axis in percent. i there a way like in excel, excel scale automacily from 0 -100% ? or it is necessary first to calculate (group by year and continent) in the dataframe?

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
fig = px.area(df, x="year", y="pop", color="continent",
          line_group="country")
fig.show()
```

thanks for helP!

Comment: try this:`fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat='%')`

Comment: Thank you for your solution. this only labels the value to percent. may i have to make my question more precise. i expect to get a percent weight (scale from 0 % to 100%)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
dfw = df.groupby(['continent','year'])['pop'].sum().to_frame()
dfw.reset_index(inplace=True)

fig = px.area(dfw, x="year", y="pop", color="continent", groupnorm='fraction')
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat='%') 
fig.show()
```

[image]